# Jquery/YUI - Find image and set CSS to display:none

Tags: jquery, yui

I have the following image in a CMS that I want to hide, I dont really want to change source code but would like to hide a specific image which does not have a class applied.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <td class="right side">
    <a title="Show only topic 1" href="view.php?id=3&topic=1">
    <img alt="Show only topic 1" src="http://vl3.co.uk/iphone/pix/i/one.gif"/>
    </a>
    <br/>
    </td>
```

I want to hide the `<a>` and the `<img>`, bare in mind the `title` and `alt` tag can be different so cant use that as an identifier.

I presume I could use `.find()` and then use `.parent()` to set the `<a>` to `display: none;` thus hiding the img?

Im inlcuding the jQuery library, however the CMS has YUI included out of the box so if anyone has a YUI method it would be appreicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YUI 2.x (w/ Selector)**

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(YAHOO.util.Selector.query(".right.side a:first"), "display", "none");
```

**YUI 2.x (w/o Selector)**

```
var rightSide = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName("right", "td")[0],
    a = rightSide.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]

YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(a, "display", "none");
```

**YUI 3.x**

```
Y.all(".right.side a:first").setStyle("display", "none");
```

Comment: Just remember that `setStyle` expects 2 `String` arguments, not an object. If you want to set many properties, `el.setStyle(top: 0, left: 0)` **will not work**. You have to call `setStyle` twice, eg. `el.setStyle('top', '0'); el.setStyle('left', '0')`.

Comment: @szeryf: For YUI3 you can use [setStyles](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_setStyles) to set multiple in a single call.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery method would be:

```
$(".right.side a:first").hide();
```

This gets the first `<a>` underneath the `class="right side"` element and sets it to `display: none`.  Be sure to replace `$` with `jQuery` if using no conflict :)

Comment: Another note: The element appears multiple times on the page, so need it to find them all.

Comment: @danit - If this same structure is used every time, change `:first` to `:first-child` and it'll find each `<a>` that's the first child on a `class="right side"` element.  If this isn't the case...will need you to post the other examples to give a working selector for that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to hide the http://vl3.co.uk/iphone/pix/i/one.gif image everywhere it shows up on the page you can do this:

```
$("img[src*='iphone/pix/i/one.gif']").parent('a').hide();
```